# clang-tidy can not find header files integrated with cmake on windows

Tags: cmake, nmake, clang-tidy

I use clang-tidy in cmake like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(clang_tidy_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# generate compile_commands.json if possible
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# dependency headers
include_directories(dependency/printer/include)

# clang-tidy
# TODO header files-not found
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy -checks=* --fix --fix-errors)

# compile executables
add_executable(test main.cpp)
```

source tree is:

```
root/
 - build/
 - dependency/
   - printer/
      - include/
        - printer.h
 - main.cpp
```

And I have a *main.cpp* for test.

```cpp
#include "printer.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Printer p;
  p.Print();
}
```

I use **NMake** as the cmake generator to create a **compile_commands.json** file for **clang-tidy**.I can compile and build *main.cpp*, but clang-tidy give a error(I skiped this with --fix-errors) saying it can not find the *printer.h*

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.obj
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E __run_co_compile --tidy=clang-tidy;-checks=*;--fix;--fix-errors --source=C:\Users\micha\Documents\test\main.cpp -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1423~1.281\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe @C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\nmAC52.tmp
C:\Users\micha\Documents\test\main.cpp:1:10: error: 'printer.h' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include "printer.h"
         ^
```

I don't know why clang-tidy can't find that header file,in *compile_commands.json* the include path is added and the final build is succeed.

Comment: I would consider using the **full path** for the include directory: `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/dependency/printer/include)`

Comment: Could you finally fix this issue?!

Comment: I haven’t fixed this issue